# C# to mySql: Failing to search a table using two parameters

Tags: c#, mysql

I am the designated GUI guy for my Database Systems final project. I have had few struggles thus far creating one thanks to [this playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLhPyEFL5u-i3Tyw0GtekMrHCukldmtf7k) but I've hit a brickwall while trying to implement my search function.

I am unable to get mySql to return any results when using **two parameters** in my command.CommandText (Ex. SELECT * from cars where **@columnName** LIKE **@searchWild**). I can get the database to return values with one or the other parameter, but not both together in the same command and I need both. I want the user to specify what column they are searching in and what value they are looking for within that column. I don't want their search to be limited to just the VIN #. They should be able to search for all Volkswagons or all Crimson colored cars, or all cars from 2007 etc by changing what category they're searching in.

Here's what the GUI looks like right now to give you an idea. Built in Windows Forms.
[DatabaseSystems Final Project Cars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvh75.png)

I tried using a stored procedure. I tried using Parameters.Add(). I tried using Parameters.AddWithValue(). The mySqlReader just can't find anything to grab after the command is executed. I can't find any post that has ran into the same problem. All the documentation on the .Add() and .AddWithValue() only give examples with ONE parameter so it wasn't much help either. I don't know what's going wrong here.

I'll try and walk you through my latest rendition:

So, you'll fill those search bars in the top right and click the big search button below. That calls this function:

```
private void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // SEARCH CARS
            if (dataGridView1.Columns.Contains("vin"))
            {
                CarDAO DAO = new CarDAO();

                // connect list to the grid view control
                myBindingSource.DataSource = DAO.SearchCars(txtSearch.Text, txtCategory.Text);

                dataGridView1.DataSource = myBindingSource;
            }

        }
```

My plan is for a bunch of those if() statements to be used to sort exactly what table we're trying to look in. We'll call the relevant DAO (Data access object) and call the Search() function specific to that DAO. Right now, I'm just trying to make it work for cars. So this if calls SearchCars():

```
internal List<Car> SearchCars(string searchTerm, string columnName)
        {
            // start with an empty list
            List<Car> returnThese = new List<Car>();

            //connect to the mysql server
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();

            string searchWild = '%' + searchTerm + '%';

            // define the sql statement to fetch all cars
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand { };
            command.Connection = connection;

            command.CommandText = "searchCars";
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("columnName", columnName);
            command.Parameters["@columnName"].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("searchTerm", searchWild);
            command.Parameters["@searchTerm"].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;

            using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Car c = new Car
                    {
                        carYear = reader.GetInt32(0),
                        carColor = reader.GetString(1),
                        carMake = reader.GetString(2),
                        carModel = reader.GetString(3),
                        carCondition = reader.GetString(4),
                        vin = reader.GetString(5)
                    };

                    returnThese.Add(c);
                }
            }
            connection.Close();

            return returnThese;
        }
```

This was the latest version using a stored procedure as you could probably tell. The stored procedure is:

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `searchCars`(IN columnName VARCHAR(15), IN searchTerm VARCHAR(40))
BEGIN
SELECT * from car WHERE columnName LIKE searchTerm;
END

I've never used a stored procedure for the record, so it might be I didn't fill it out right. But I got no syntax errors and comparing it to other SPs online... anyway. It doesn't work.

Here is what I thought my best attempt was without using a SP:

```
internal List<Car> SearchCars(string searchTerm, string columnName)
        {
            // start with an empty list
            List<Car> returnThese = new List<Car>();

            //connect to the mysql server
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();

            string searchWild = '%' + searchTerm + '%';

            // define the sql statement to fetch all cars
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand { };
            command.Connection = connection;

            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM car WHERE @columnName LIKE @searchWild";

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@columnName", columnName);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchWild", searchWild);

            //string query = command.CommandText;
            //foreach (MySqlParameter p in command.Parameters) { query = query.Replace(p.ParameterName, p.Value.ToString()); }
            //Console.WriteLine(query);

            using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Car c = new Car
                    {
                        carYear = reader.GetInt32(0),
                        carColor = reader.GetString(1),
                        carMake = reader.GetString(2),
                        carModel = reader.GetString(3),
                        carCondition = reader.GetString(4),
                        vin = reader.GetString(5)
                    };

                    returnThese.Add(c);
                }
            }
            connection.Close();

            return returnThese;
        }
```

During execution, The reader never manages to find anything. It skips the while() loop entirely resulting in the function returning an empty list. Where am I going wrong here?

The final report is due tomorrow at midnight. I have implemented Insert, View, and Delete. I still need to implement update to get all the CRUD operations functional so I'll be working on that until someone hopefully responds here... Thanks for reading. I've never posted here before. Do let me know how I could've formatted this better if you are a cultured stackoverflow-er!

Comment: AFAIK a column name is not something you can parameterize. That usually falls under the heading of "Dynamic SQL" - something else entirely.

Comment: Does your user type directly the column name or they choose the names from a predefined and not modifiable set of names?

Comment: @Steve The user types directly and assumes all faults if their case or spelling is bad. There is a component I believe that I could use instead that gives a little dropdown menu to select from and is not modifiable.

Comment: @topsail :/ darn. Time to learn about Dynamic SQL at least. Thanks.

Comment: I think your non-SP version is better. If you could constrain your column name input to ensure you only ever allow correct column names, you could change your SQL to be... `"SELECT * FROM car WHERE [" + columnName + "] LIKE @searchWild"`, and only use the command parameter on your search value. To ensure the column names input by the user, I would limit the input to a predefined drop down list AND in the code I would always check the input column name received was in a valid column name list. The value you use in the query would always from the come list in code and never use the one received.

Comment: Fantastic idea that has given me an idea. Thanks quaabaam!